# How do I update Canvas Arc by Angular directive?

Tags: angularjs, canvas, angularjs-directive, html5-canvas

Is there a way to update canvas arc from Angular's directive?
I want to update start/end angles, radius and color.

This is the HTML:

```
<canvas class="canvasIndicator" ng-style="styleArcByCurrentStatus()"></canvas>`
```

This is my directive

```
    (function (angular) {
    'use strict';
    var app = angular.module('mdlName.directives');

    app.directive('directiveName', [function(){
        return{
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            templateUrl:'directiveTpl.html',

            scope:{
            },

            link: function(scope, element, attrs){
                scope.canvasIndicator = angular.element( document.querySelector(".canvasIndicator"));
                scope.canvasContext = scope.canvasIndicator.context.getContext("2d");

                scope.secondsParameters = {x: 49, y:68, radius:12, lineWidth:25, color:'#80dcf1'};

                var x = scope.secondsParameters.x,
                    y = scope.secondsParameters.y,
                    radius = scope.secondsParameters.radius;

                scope.canvasContext.arc(x, y, radius, (1.5 * Math.PI), Math.PI, true);

                scope.canvasContext.lineWidth = scope.secondsParameters.lineWidth;
                scope.canvasContext.strokeStyle = scope.secondsParameters.color;
                scope.canvasContext.stroke();

                scope.styleArcByCurrentStatus = function(){
                    var x = scope.secondsParameters.x,
                        y = scope.secondsParameters.y,
                        radius = scope.secondsParameters.radius;

                    scope.canvasContext.arc(x, y, radius, (1 * Math.PI), Math.PI, true);

                    scope.canvasContext.lineWidth = Math.floor(Math.random()*(20-1+1)+1);
                    scope.canvasContext.strokeStyle = scope.secondsParameters.color;
                    scope.canvasContext.stroke();
                }
            }
        }
    }]);

})(angular);
```

the usage of ng-style is only to catch the digest loop of angular to update the arc.
In this example I try to update the arc's line width, but also need to update arc's start angle, end angle, ...

The link function is called and the "styleArcByCurrentStatus" is been called (for each digest loop)

Is this possible?
Possible to dynamically update arc by Angular?

Thank you very much.